# Get the current fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using a `NavigationDrawer` Activity (predefined view in AndroidStudio) and I need to put (and get) the current fragment to switch between fragments.

I saw in some places to put visible and hidden the fragments but I have more than 3 so I need to identify all the fragments before switch between thems.

How can I solved? I just only find to set Tags at the moment to be displayed or set the visibility.

Comment: Could you add some code to your question please?  It makes it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the fragment, you should use a tag

```
fragTrans.replace(android.R.id.content, myFragment, "SearchingFrag");
```

So that later if you want to check if the fragment is visible:

```
 MyFragment Frag =      
 (MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("SearchingFrag");
   if (Frag.isVisible()) {
     // add your code 
   }
```

if you want more help inform me hope you got an idea from my answer